# upload datas with a file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, strapi

I want to upload my data with an image. I've searching for similar case but I've found help only for data or only for upload but never the two together.

The form is between line 3 - 36 and I call **enregistreAjout** method

Datas like title, category are added to strapi but not the picture.

Im using strapi 3 and vuejs 2

What am i doing wrong ?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- ############# AJOUTER / MODIFIER ############# -->

    <!-- Si boutonAjouMod est true on affiche le bouton Ajouter -->
    <div class="btn btn-outline-primary" v-if="boutonAjouMod" v-on:click="toggleAfficheAjouter">{{boutonAjouter}}</div><!-- je clique on lance la méthode toggleafficheAjouMod -->

    <!-- Si afficheAjouMod est true on affiche le formulaire d'ajout -->
    <form action="" class="mt-4" v-if="afficheAjouMod">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Titre</label>
          <input v-model="titre" type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required />
      </div>      
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category">Catégorie</label>
          <select v-model="categorie" class="form-control" required>
          <option selected>----</option>
          <option value="job">maison</option>
          <option value="rent">appartement</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="content">Commentaire</label>
          <textarea v-model="commentaire" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" required></textarea>
      </div>    
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="picture">Image</label>
          <!-- v-model ne fonctionne pas il faut utiliser v-on:change -->          
          <input type="file" id="file" name="picture" ref="file" class="form-control" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"/>
          <br><img src="../../assets/default.jpg" alt=""><br>
      </div>           
      <input type="hidden">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" v-on:click="enregistreAjout">Enregistrer</button> 
      <!--<div class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" v-on:click="enregistreAjout">Enregistrer</div>-->
      <div class="btn btn-xs" v-on:click="toggleAfficheAjouter">Annuler</div>
    </form>

    <!-- ############# VOIR ############# -->

    <!-- Si afficheVue est true on affiche la vue -->
    <div v-if="afficheVue">
      <h3>{{titre}}</h3>
      <br>
      <label for="category">Type : {{categorie}}</label>
      <br>
      <label for="content">{{commentaire}}</label>
      <br>
      <label for="picture"><img v-bind:src="completeImgUrl(image)" v-bind:alt="titre"/></label>
      <br>
      <div class="btn btn-xs btn-primary mt-2" v-on:click="toogleAfficheView">Retour</div> 
    </div>   

    <!-- ############# TABLEAU ############# -->

    <!-- Si afficheTableau est true on affiche le tableau -->
    <div  v-if="afficheTableau">
      <h1 class="text-center">Annonces</h1>
      <!--barre de recherche-->
      <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher par titre" />

      <!-- Affichage du tableau -->
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Titre</th>
            <th scope="col">Catégorie</th>
            <th scope="col">Commentaire</th>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Debut affichage tableau dynamique -->
          <tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(annonce,index) in toutesLesAnnonces" > <!-- Index obligatoire pour boucle for -->
            <td>{{annonce.title}}</td>
            <td>{{annonce.category}}</td>
            <td>{{annonce.content}}</td>                            
            <td>
              <img v-bind:src="completeImgUrl(annonce.picture.formats.thumbnail.url)" v-bind:alt="annonce.title"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success mt-5 ms-3 me-2" v-bind:value=annonce.id>Modifier</div>
              <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mt-5 me-2" v-on:click="toogleAfficheView(annonce.id)" v-bind:value=annonce.id>Voir</div>
              <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger mt-5" v-bind:value=annonce.id>Supprimer</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- Fin affichage tableau dynamique -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>
```

Scripts

```
<script>
    //valeurs globales
    import constantes from'../global/constantes' 

    //appel d'une fonction globale
    import {getWithExpiry} from '../global/Fonctions.js' 

    //gestion des API
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'AccueilDisplay',
        data() { 
            return {
                //token jwt
                token: '',

                //variables Cacher/Voir les balises
                boutonAjouMod: true,
                afficheAjouMod: false,
                afficheVue: false,
                afficheTableau: true,
                boutonAjouter: 'Ajouter une annonce',
                toutesLesAnnonces: [],

                //upload image
                file: null,
                //isImage: false,
                //previewImage = '',

                //Voir / Ajouter
                titre: '',
                categorie: '',
                commentaire: '',
                image: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
          toggleAfficheAjouter: function(){ //affiche / cache Ajouter
            this.afficheAjouMod=!this.afficheAjouMod //est égale au contraire de la valeur précente
            this.afficheTableau=!this.afficheTableau
          },          
          completeImgUrl: function(ImgLink){ //sert à ajouter l'url complete pour l'image
            return constantes.serveurapi + ImgLink
          },
          handleFileUpload: function(){ // recuperation de l'image
            this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
            //console.log(this.file)
            /*
            if (
              this.file.name.includes(".png") ||
              this.file.name.includes(".jpg")
            ) {
              this.isImage = true;
              this.previewImage = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
            } else {
              this.isImage = false;
            }
            */
          },
          /*enregistreAjout: function(){
            //console.log(this.token)
          },*/
          async enregistreAjout() {
            try {
                await axios.post(`${constantes.serveurapi}/${constantes.collectionAnnonces}`, {
                    title: this.titre,
                    category: this.categorie,
                    content: this.commentaire
                  }, {  
                    headers : {
                      'content-type': 'application/json',
                      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
                    }                     
                  })                      
                  .then((envoiData) => {
                  console.log("envoiData",envoiData)  
                  console.log("files",this.file)  
                  const formData = new FormData();
                  formData.append("files",this.file)
  
                  formData.append("ref","annonce")
                  formData.append("refId",envoiData.id)// quel est l'id
                  formData.append("field","file")//quel est le champ
                  console.log("formData",formData)
                 
                  axios.post(`${constantes.serveurapi}/upload`, {
                    body: formData
                    },{
                      headers : {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
                      }                    
                    })  
                  })   
            } catch(e) {
                this.error = true
            } 
        },       
          toogleAfficheView: function(id){ // affiche / cache Vue
            this.afficheTableau=!this.afficheTableau
            this.afficheVue=!this.afficheVue
            if (!this.afficheTableau) {   // si on desactive le tableau alors on affiche la vue  
              this.boutonAjouMod = !this.boutonAjouMod   // on vire le boutron ajouter      
              const chercheObjet = this.toutesLesAnnonces.find(element => element.id === id) //on recherche l'objet par son id
              this.titre = chercheObjet['title']
              this.categorie = chercheObjet['category']
              this.commentaire = chercheObjet['content']
              this.image = chercheObjet['picture']['formats']['thumbnail']['url']              
            } else {
              this.boutonAjouMod = !this.boutonAjouMod //sinon on affiche le tableau et on remet le bouton ajouter
              this.titre = '' //on remet à vide
              this.categorie = ''
              this.commentaire = ''
              this.image = ''              
            }
          }
        },
        created() { // partie affichage du tableau lors création de l'affichage
          const getuser = getWithExpiry("user")
          this.token = JSON.parse(getuser).jwt
          axios.get(`${constantes.serveurapi}/${constantes.collectionAnnonces}` , { 
              headers : {
                  'content-type': 'application/json',
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
              }
          })
          .then(reponse => {
            //console.log(reponse.data)
            for (const annonce of reponse.data) {
              this.toutesLesAnnonces.push(annonce)
            }
          })
          .catch(err=>{
             console.log(err)
          })
        }
    }

</script>
```

So far I've tried this :

```
  async enregistreAjout() {
    try {
        await axios.post(`${constantes.serveurapi}/${constantes.collectionAnnonces}`, {
            title: this.titre,
            category: this.categorie,
            content: this.commentaire
          }, {  
            headers : {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
            }                     
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("response",response) 
            console.log("files",this.file)  
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files",this.file)  
            formData.append("ref","annonce")
            formData.append("refId",response.data.id)// quel est l'id
            formData.append("field","picture")//quel est le champ
            console.log("formData",formData)                 
            return axios.post(`${constantes.serveurapi}/upload`, {
              body: formData,
              },{
                headers : {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
                }                    
              })  
            }) 
      } catch(error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
  }
```

And I get an error 400 bad request. It's really hard to resolve this.

Comment: I was ban for low quality answer but I've got a solution. Sorry I can't poste solution here. For those interested here a link https://forum.strapi.io/t/vuejs-post-data-then-link-uploded-file-error-400/12606/2